# Mejorar consulta mysql like concat('%', campo ,'%')

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de mejorar una consulta mysql, la cual me arroja los datos que necesito pero de una manera muy lenta. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es comparar dos campos de dos tablas diferentes, la tabla A tiene un campo telefonos, y la table B tiene un campo patron, entonces estoy buscando las coincidencias de tabla B.patron en la tabla A.telefono. Para eso estuve usando

```
$sql = "SELECT n.id_local,n.documento,n.telefono,
n.fecha_ingresado,n.operador,n.empresa as 
'empresaImportada',n.cartera,r.sin_15, r.tipo, r.empresa as 
'empresaValidar',r.modalidad,
r.localidad,r.reemplazar_por,
r.caracteres from normalizacion_telefonos_validar n
left join referencia_completa r ON
n.telefono like CONCAT('%',r.sin_15,'%') 
WHERE n.fecha_ingresado='$fecha' AND n.cartera='$cartera' AND n.empresa= 
'$empresa'
GROUP by n.id;";
```

consulta que demora 180 segundos o mas.

El tiempo de ejecucion lo mejore con esta sentencia que me la recomendo un companero de la comunidad. @David JP

```
  SELECT n.id_local,n.documento,n.telefono,n.fecha_ingresado,
    n.operador,n.empresa as 'empresaImportada',n.cartera,r.sin_15,
      r.tipo, r.empresa as 'empresaValidar',r.modalidad,
      r.localidad,r.reemplazar_por,
      r.caracteres from normalizacion_telefonos_validar n
       left join referencia_completa r ON
       n.telefono WHERE LOCATE(sin_15,n.telefono)  
     GROUP by n.id;
```

el problema de esta es que trae solamente los que concide, y por eso uso el left join, porque necesito todos los datos, asi coincidan o no para yo despues tomar desiciones con los que conciden o no.

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `normalizacion_telefonos_validar` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_local` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `documento` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_ingresado` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
   `operador` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
   `empresa` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cartera` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `fecha_ingresado` (`fecha_ingresado`),
   KEY `empresa` (`empresa`),
  KEY `cartera` (`cartera`),
 KEY `telefono` (`telefono`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2828 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



  INSERT INTO `normalizacion_telefonos_validar` (`id`, `id_local`, 
 `documento`, 
`telefono`, `fecha_ingresado`, `operador`, `empresa`, `cartera`) VALUES
(1, '1', '1239872628', '1147431313', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
 'otra'),
(2, '2', '2345079519', '111557134041', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
 'otra'),
(3, '3', '456503415', '47230705', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
 'otra'),
(4, '4', '678221425', '2374624920', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
 'otra'),
(5, '5', '678221425', '2374624920', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
 'otra'),
(6, '6', '31321425', '2374624920', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
 'otra'),
(7, '7', '343427105', '1144410675', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
  'otra'),
(8, '8', '3123718343', '1536850491', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
'otra'),
(9, '9', '209223457', '1143933720', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
  'otra'),
     (10, '10', '20235441159', '112000000000', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 
   'empresa', 
   'otra'),
   (11, '10', '2345159', '1159045556', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
    'otra'),
    (12, '11', '21235303982', '48314579', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
   'otra'),
     (13, '12', '3353305', '47546175', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
    'otra'),
    (14, '12', '312317305', '47134411', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
   'otra'),
    (15, '12', '30345305', '45196331', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
     'otra'),
    (16, '13', '12377175', '1164939751', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 
  'otra'),
    (17, '13', '368756777175', '46338690', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 
    'empresa', 
      'otra'),
      (18, '14', '3123437220', '111521628770', '2020-10-27', 'Express', 
    'empresa', 
     'otra')
```

y aqui la otra tabla que sirve como referencia

[tabla referencia](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MIN0_LWNfZFm39n9lAcbGhFt-RT9Y922IqILwyAzk-Q/edit?usp=sharing)

### Dataset

Aporto el dataset de una forma un poco más compacta:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `normalizacion_telefonos_validar` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_local` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `documento` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_ingresado` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operador` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empresa` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cartera` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `fecha_ingresado` (`fecha_ingresado`),
  KEY `empresa` (`empresa`),
  KEY `cartera` (`cartera`),
  KEY `telefono` (`telefono`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2828 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE referencia_completa(
  IDENTIFICACION DOUBLE,
  LINEA VARCHAR(100),
  transformado VARCHAR(100),
  EMPRESA VARCHAR(100),
  SERVICIO VARCHAR(100),
  MODALIDAD VARCHAR(100),
  LOCALIDAD DOUBLE,
  REEMPLAZAR_POR DOUBLE,
  LARGO VARCHAR(100),
  CENTRAL VARCHAR(100),
  A_UTILIZAR VARCHAR(100),
  caracteres DOUBLE
);

INSERT INTO `normalizacion_telefonos_validar` (
  `id`, `id_local`, `documento`, `telefono`, 
  `fecha_ingresado`, `operador`, `empresa`, `cartera`
  ) VALUES
  (1, '1', '1239872628', '1147431313', 
    '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 'otra'),
  (2, '2', '2345079519', '111557134041', 
    '2020-10-27', 'Express', 'empresa', 'otra');

INSERT INTO referencia_completa(
  IDENTIFICACION, LINEA, transformado, EMPRESA, SERVICIO, MODALIDAD, 
  LOCALIDAD, REEMPLAZAR_POR, LARGO, CENTRAL, A_UTILIZAR, caracteres
  ) VALUES
  (114730, 'SIN 15', 'empresaEquis', 'SBT', 'BASICA', 
    'AMBA', 11, 4730, 'SC 2233/98', '2-Oct-98', '$54$11$4730$', 6),
  (114731, 'SIN 15', 'empresaEquis', 'SBT', 'BASICA', 
    'AMBA', 11, 4731, 'SC 2233/98', '2-Oct-98', '$54$11$4731$', 6);
```

[image: DESCRIBE normalizacion_telefonos_validar;]

describe normalizacion_telefonos_validar

y este es el explain de la ultima consulta que me proporcionaste

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para intentar replicar la situación y poder realizar comprobaciones, aporta un dataset con phpMyAdmin->exportar e indica el resultado que esperas para esos datos de muestra. No es necesaria toda la base de datos, con unos cuantos registros significativos por tabla es suficiente

Comment: Listo, actualizado en la pregunta

Comment: Con phpMyAdmin y exportar deberías obtener un fichero de texto plano con las sentencias SQL que permiten replicar tu base de datos. Quitas los datos que sobran y pegas lo que te queda en modo texto utilizando Ctrl+k, no pegues pantallazos que no vamos a teclear los datos de una foto... :) Dame un par de minutos para ampliar mi respuesta que ya he visto qué te está pasando...

Comment: Eso es. Aunque necesitamos las dos tablas implicadas y el resultado que esperas obtener para esos datos de ejemplo, a ver si consigo averiguar para qué necesitas el `GROUP BY`. La captura de pantalla puedes eliminarla

Comment: Hola, Alvaro. Para saber cómo mejorar la consulta, es necesario que hagas una prueba: la ejecutes directamente en MySQL y uses la opción EXPLAIN. Puedes revisar en el WorkBench [así](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-tutorial-visual-explain-dbt3.html). El objetivo es ver cómo está corriendo esa consulta en el motor, pues hay cosas como el join con un LIKE que seguramente son muy costosas. Hay índice de algún tipo en el campo telefono? Por favor, procura incluir en tu pregunta la definición de las tablas (`DESCRIBE normalizacion_telefonos_validar ` nos da esa información como texto)

Comment: Estás haciendo un cruce entre las tablas donde, por cada registro en la tabla `n`, tienes que generar el LIKE de TODOS los registros en el campo `sin_15` y ver si alguno encaja. Eso va a crecer proporcional a la cantidad de registros en las tablas y se va a tardar horrores. De nuevo, sugiero que hagas el EXPLAIN, manual o en el workbench, y compares ese LIKE con un JOIN normalito (así no tire datos, es para ver cómo eligiría el optimizador de la BD correr la consulta). Por último, seguimos sin saber qué clase de dato viene en `sin_15` como para justificar hacer un JOIN con un LIKE

Comment: Es necesario que uses todos los datos de la dataset que te proporcione, ya que esos datos son los que dan "coinciden" (llamemoslo asi), en el cruce de datos de las dos tablas. Entonces esos dos dataset que te envie, en informacion relevante para simular el entorno, donde tenemos que buscar en referencia_telefonos_validar, que encuentre el patron  sin_15 de la tabla referencia_completa, si consigue ese patron en el campo TELEFONO de la tabla referencia_telefonos_validar, entonces ese telefono pasa a ser valido.

Comment: Por eso es importante toda la data que brindé, tanto en la pregunta como en el link. Por otro lado. si hice los explain de la consulta y me dice que le tengo que poner un indice a telefono de la tabla referencia_telefonos_validar, la cual tiene dicho indice.

Comment: el telefono on like concat ('%',sin_15,'%') = donde coincida el patron sin_15, traeme la fila completa del patron_sin 15.

Comment: No entiendo cómo te funciona un dato como campo... yo sigo obteniendo ` Unknown column 'r.sin_15' in 'field list'`

Comment: Disculpa mi amigo @David JP. En campo. Iria. Like concat ('%',n.sin_15,'%'). sin_15 es un campo de la tabla referencia completa, esta tabla te la deje en un link de la pregunta. Vinculado a un drive

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/d/1MIN0_LWNfZFm39n9lAcbGhFt-RT9Y922IqILwyAzk-Q/mobilebasic

Comment: muestrame la consulta que haces. el campo =>  sin_15 es la columna que existe en referencia_completa

Comment: En la tabla `referencia_completa` hay un campo `LINEA` que contiene un dato `SIN 15` en algunos registros. `SIN 15` es un dato, no un campo...

Comment: Tienes razon. Se cambio el nombre por error, o lo cambie por error. No existe el campo linea. En realidad es sin_15. Y sin_15 como columna contiene patrones. Disculpe amigo david. Lo modificare.

Comment: Entonces, ¿cómo ha quedado esta pregunta? ¿Has conseguido el resultado que esperabas?

Comment: Por ahora no amigo David, sigo con la misma consulta like concat.

Answer (score 2):

Una cosa tienes que tener clara: en PHP siempre será más lento. Porque, necesariamente, tienes que mover los datos del servidor mysql al servidor web para, después, realizar las comparaciones. Mientras que, desde mysql, directamente comparas los datos que necesites.

Centrados en MySQL, te sugiero:

- Evita el `LIKE` y utiliza `LOCATE()`.
- Realiza los `WHERE` antes del `JOIN`, no te preocupes por las subconsultas, si tienes muchos registros, tendrás mucho menor trasiego a memoria.
- Crea índices en las tablas. Un simple, `ALTER TABLE tabla ADD INDEX(campo)` reducirá tu tiempo de ejecución drásticamente.
- Reescribe la consulta con `IN` en vez de `LEFT JOIN` y compara el execution plan.

La parte más lenta y costosa de tu consulta es la del producto cartesiano en la que combinas todos con todos con ese `LEFT JOIN` que no entiendo muy bien para qué usas porque, en el `ON`, sólo utilizas un campo... Por favor, ejecuta esta consulta y dime el tiempo que consume:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id,telefono FROM normalizacion_telefonos_validar
  ) n JOIN (
    SELECT sin_15 FROM referencia_completa
  ) r WHERE LOCATE(sin_15,n.telefono);
```

Una vez que tengas los teléfonos que necesitas, ahora ya puedes ir a por el resto de la información con:

```
SELECT n.id_local,n.documento,n.telefono,n.fecha_ingresado,
  n.operador,n.empresa as 'empresaImportada',n.cartera,
  r.sin_15,r.tipo, r.empresa as 'empresaValidar',r.modalidad,
  r.localidad,r.reemplazar_por,r.caracteres  
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT id,telefono FROM normalizacion_telefonos_validar
      ) n JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT sin_15 FROM referencia_completa
      ) r WHERE LOCATE(sin_15,n.telefono) 
  ) c1 JOIN normalizacion_telefonos_validar n USING(id)
  JOIN referencia_completa r USING(sin_15)
  GROUP by n.id;
```

Tampoco entiendo muy bien para qué usas el `GROUP BY` si no totalizas ningún campo, pero bueno, igual quieres un dato cualquiera de cada grupo que haces, ni idea, tú sabrás. Para poder ayudarte más ya necesitaría el dataset, hasta aquí es todo lo que puedo hacer a ciegas, sin conocer la estructura de las tablas, ni datos de muestra, ni lo que esperas obtener.

Ya me vas comentando...

Comment: gracias por la recomendacion David

Comment: David he intentado acomodar la sentecia con las recomendacione que me diste pero tengo error de sintaxis. Te podria mostrar lo que llevo hasta ahora

Comment: SELECT n.id_local,n.documento,n.telefono,n.fecha_ingresado,n.operador,n.empresa as 'empresaImportada',n.cartera from normalizacion_telefonos_validar n
WHERE n.telefono IN (SELECT sin_15 FROM referencia_completa WHERE LOCATE(sin_15,n.telefono));  es la consulta que tengo, no me arroja ningun resultado

Comment: SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id,telefono FROM normalizacion_telefonos_validar
  ) n JOIN (
    SELECT sin_15 FROM referencia_completa
  ) r WHERE LOCATE(sin_15,n.telefono); esta duro 28 segundos ,     y la segunda consulta duro 1:28 min.   Las tablas que subi, son de prueba, realmente la tabla referencia_completa tiene 92.620 filas, y la tabla normalizacion_telefonos_validar tiene 2.500 a veces , 5.000 y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: Es que 100k x 5k = 500M de comprobaciones, 28 seg. me parece hasta poco... Te he modificado la consulta incluyendo un `DISTINCT` a ver si reducimos un poco el número de comparaciones... La otra piedra en el zapato es el `GROUP BY`, ¿te arreglarías con otro `DISTINCT` o realmente necesitas agrupar?

Comment: Pudiste revisar las tablas que ingrese en la pregunta y el link? La utima sentencia con el distinct tiene un tiempo de ejecucion de mas de 5 minutos

Comment: Pues sí, y he visto que haces referencia a un campo llamado `sin_15` que en realidad es un dato el campo `LINEA`, ¿podrías aclarármelo? Edito tu pregunta con el dataset un poco más compacto. Si crees que algún registro es relevante, por favor, añádelo... y elimina la información redundante a ver si simplificando y aclarando la pregunta encontramos la solución